# filepicker.io add options to makedrop pane

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

Can you tell me how to set the options for the makedroppane function I cannot figure it out. Here is my example code.

I know it needs to be a dictionary array but I am not sure were to put it.  In the example it just has the [0].  An example in the actual docs of the options setting would be nice.

```
filepicker.setKey('###########');
var options = {
    "multiple": true
};
filepicker.makeDropPane($('#exampleDropPane')[0],options, {
    dragEnter: function() {
        $("#exampleDropPane").html("Drop to upload");
    },
    dragLeave: function() {
        $("#exampleDropPane").html("Drop files here");
    },
    progress: function(percentage) {
        $("#exampleDropPane").text("Uploading ("+percentage+"%)");
        $("#pb").css('width', (percentage)+'%');
    },
    done: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert('done');
    }
});
```

Comment: BTW: they charge money, they should provide support.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you just need to combine your options into one map:

```
filepicker.makeDropPane($('#exampleDropPane')[0], {
   multiple: true,
   dragEnter: function() {
    //  $("#pb").addClass('show');
    $("#exampleDropPane").html("Drop to upload");
   },
   dragLeave: function() {
    //      $("#pb").addClass('show');
    $("#exampleDropPane").html("Drop files here");
   }, ...
  });
```

The syntax is `filepicker.makeDropPane(dropPane, options)` - more information at https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#local-drop

Comment: Create that solved it.  I knew it was something simple maybe and example in your docs would make it clear.

Comment: Great! You may want to mark the answer as solved for future searchers