# filepicker.io drag and drop with images over 2 meg

Tags: filepicker.io

Whenever I use the filepicker.io I get the following error with images that over 2 meg using the drag and drop method.

Uncaught ReferenceError: DIALOG_URL is not defined

The html is as follows.

```
<div class='draganddropimage uploadhelp' id="exampleDropPane">
</div>
```

and the javascript is

```
filepicker.setKey('xxxxx');
var options = {
    "multiple": true
   };
filepicker.makeDropPane($('#exampleDropPane')[0],
{
  multiple: true,
           mimetypes: 'image/*',
           maxsize:"10485760", 

        dragEnter: function() {
              //    $("#pb").addClass('show');

            $("#exampleDropPane").html("Drop to upload");
        },
        dragLeave: function() {
            //      $("#pb").addClass('show');

            $("#exampleDropPane").html("Drop files here");
        },
        progress: function(percentage) {

            $("#exampleDropPane").text("Uploading ("+percentage+"%)");
            // alert(percentage);
       //   $("#pb").css('width', (percentage)+'%');

        },
        dragError: function(data)
        {
            //alert(data);
            console.log('grrr errro');
        },
        done: function(data) {

            //console.log("fn:"+data[0].data.filename);
            //$("#pb").css('width', (0)+'%');
            //fileUploaded(data);
            imageupload(data);
    },
    error:function(type, message) {
        console.log(message);
                    $("#exampleDropPane").html("Sorry Images and PDF files only");

    }
});
```

any help will be most helpful

Thanks

Chris

Comment: You should reduce your sample code to a minimum. For example what is "options" used for?

Comment: its the options in for the filepicker.  I feel it is better to show the code that is used as opposed to an edited version of the code as the bug may be in that code that has been removed.

Comment: Your code does not use the option variable, it specifies the options below the makeDropPane(). (As discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559123/filepicker-io-add-options-to-makedrop-pane). Yes you should only show the code you have actually tried, but it is good to try the smallest example, it often helps to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks eckes, I will make a note to do that in the future.

Comment: hello,

I resolved it. 

The issue was I was calling the js vis https.  When I changed it to //api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js it worked fine.

Thanks

Chris